# Google Spreadsheets (app-script) Add duplicate row after selecting drop down from a cell with data validation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying add a duplicate row after selecting from a drop down list in a cell with data validation, after I click the drop down, I want it to add a new row below the current row with the same formulas. I can't seem to manipulate this the right way to copy down my formula from my third column(it copies my data validation perfectly). I also don't know how to add the function for the drop down. If you can help at all please let me know. I'll share the spreadsheet.

Spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AiRmDcJRv_f2dDFGNDRCYWtBUmU2TE9hUlI1ZkVZYWc&usp=sharing

I was using this guide to try to write/mo my script but am having no luck
[Google Spreadsheets (app-script) copying a row of information to another spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223625/google-spreadsheets-app-script-copying-a-row-of-information-to-another-spreads/14966567#14966567)

Thank You again!